# DateTime object creation on MySQL non null field

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a MySQL table with a `DATETIME NOT NULL` data type (didn't specify default value).

For MySQL default, if I don't specify data, the value will become `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Then I fetch the value from database, which value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. Then I try to create a DateTime object with the retrieved data.

```
$date = new DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
$formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $formatted_date; // which display -0001-11-30, an obvious invalid date
```

What is the best way to check if the value is not a valid date ?

Comment: `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` is a valid date.

Comment: But `0000-00-00 00:00:00 != -0001-11-30`, Sir.

Comment: If you sometimes don't enter a date into the field, make it `NULL`.

Comment: `DateTime` expects the parameter to be a timestamp " the $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00)." http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php

Comment: @Stephan not true. `new DateTime('2013-06-04');` is valid.

Comment: @Stephan There is way more that that is supported http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check column with [`NULLIF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) function:

```
SELECT NULLIF('0000-00-00 00:00:01', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
// Shows 0000-00-00 00:00:01

SELECT NULLIF('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '0000-00-00 00:00:00');
// Shows NULL
```

However, I suggest to apply what @**deceze** said:

> If you sometimes don't enter a date into the field, make it NULL

Data should be stored in appropriate form. So I suggest to `ALTER` your table column to accept `NULL`s.

***UPDv1:***

If you don't need computations with dates in PHP, and need just to output it, I also would suggest to use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) as it is more reliable in this matter:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('0000-00-00 00:00:00', '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s');
// Shows '00.00.0000 00:00:00'
```

Comment: @ShivanRaptor `NULL` is more easy to check though. You need more?

Answer (score 1):

```
$formatted_date = "";
if($data['row'] != "0000-00-00 00:00:00")
{
  $date = new DateTime('0000-00-00 00:00:00');
  $formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
echo $formatted_date;
```